# Cannot access a disposed object inside using statement (HttpWebResponse)

Tags: c#, .net-4.0, httpwebrequest

I have the following code snippet:

```cs
public static byte[] DownloadResults() {
    HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url);
    request.Method = "GET";
    request.Timeout = 10 * 1000;

    using (HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
    using (Stream stream = response.GetResponseStream())
    using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(stream))
    {
        if (response.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            var json = reader.ReadToEnd();
            throw new Exception(json);
        }

        // Decompress bytes
        using (GZipStream decompressor = new GZipStream(stream, CompressionMode.Decompress))
        using (MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        {
            decompressor.CopyTo(memoryStream); // This line fails on rare occasions
            return memoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

99% of the time, this function works without any issues. However, very rarely it will throw an exception on the `decompressor.CopyTo(memoryStream)` line:

```
System.ObjectDisposedException: Cannot access a disposed object.
Object name: 'System.Net.Connection'.
   at System.Net.ConnectStream.Read(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size)
   at System.IO.Compression.DeflateStream.Read(Byte[] array, Int32 offset, Int32 count)
   at System.IO.Stream.InternalCopyTo(Stream destination, Int32 bufferSize)
   at RMCClient.DownloadResults() RMCClient.cs:line 390
```

My question is... under what circumstances is this possible? I thought wrapping in `using` statements guaranteed that the underlying streams would not be closed or disposed of until after going out of scope.

Comment: Can you please clarify how you got "using statements guaranteed that the underlying streams would not be closed or disposed of until after going out of scope" from [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/using-statement) "The using declaration calls the Dispose method on the object in the correct way when it goes out of scope"?

Comment: It must be just a false assumption I had. So you are saying there are other mechanisms that can cause a resource to be disposed inside a using statement without explicitly calling `Dispose`?

Comment: To be precise I tried to point out that `using` in no way protects object from being disposed - it only makes sure it is disposed at the end. Anything else can dispose that object before `using` calls dispose. Unfortunately it does not really help to make question answerable, but open up more ways for you to debug - something else can dispose/close stream *while* your code is running on that thread. (Looking at the exception it is quite clear that network is terminated, so there is likely not much you can do about it)